# Medium particle velocity vs wave velocity

Tags: waves

It is said that wave may have a uniform velocity. We could think of the time when exactly the  1/3 th wavepulse  has finished pasing through this point,  and 2/3th numbered wave pulse would do this after twice the time elapsed, etc.
But it is worth noting that any individual particle of the medium may oscillate up and down, not with an uniform velocity(restoring force is proportional to displacement). Isn't it contradictory, in the sense that the overall wave should not have itself a uniform velocity, rather than an average?

Comment: I think you are confusing the spatial ensemble average of the particle motions with individual particle motions.  In media with oscillations as you describe, they often exhibit a collective behavior.  The wave velocity results from the ensemble average (i.e., collective behavior) of the particles, not the individual particles within any given part of a wave packet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the motion of the wave and the motion of the individual particles of the medium which transmits the wave. Of course the velocity of the wave is uniform while the velocity of the particles varies during the cycle of oscillation. 'The wave' itself is seen in the progress eg of a peak through the medium, from one particle to another. (Possibly I saying the same as honeste_vivere !)

Answer (score -3):

For a wave having the equation

```
   y=A sin(wt-kx)
```

the velocity of the wave is given by

v=fλ.
Since w=2πf and k=2π/λ,

v=w/k.

The particle velocity at any instant is obtained by partially differentiating the wave equation wrt time to give

∂y/∂t=Awcos(wt-kx).

So the velocity of the particle is not uniform (varies with t and x),however the velocity of the wave is itself constant (as frequency and wavelength are fixed). The wave velocity is an average of the motions of the individual particles of the medium.
What we observe as bulk is different from an individual motion.

Comment: This needs more sentences to be useful. Edit please.